# Using Sympy and Miktex with Spyder?

Tags: sympy, spyder, miktex

I've installed Miktex for my user from the Miktex website to get Latex outputs of sympy expressions. When I use pretty print, the unicode printer is used. If I force with "use_latex = True" as an argument for init_printing, I get no output in my Ipython console. Any idea how to fix this?

I am aware in a notebook I can get Latex printing by default but would like to stick with Spyder.

Comment: turns out the printing was working but displayed as a figure and these plots only show up in the plots window until i switched off "mute inline plotting"